# Using modelbuilder.HasKey() causes error in entity framework new migrations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

I have some entities that have composite key as primary key.
I configured them using fluentApi to set composite key, like:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<EntityWithCompositeKey>().HasKey(entity => new { entity.Property1, entity.Property2});
```

But I get an error when I want to Updata-Database after adding a new migration:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: To change the IDENTITY property of a column, the column needs to be dropped and recreated.
```

After some digging I realized that is because of those settings in fluentApi to set composite key, I think entity framework wants to change the primary key of the entity to set new composite key and I get this error... Am I right??? Where did I go wrong?

I can't update my database because of this error and every time I need to delete migrations folder and database and recreate them so new changes can take place, and it's getting so annoying as we are getting closer to production.

I'm using Entity Framework 5rc1 and Asp.Net Core 3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are updating the primary key of a column, you need to delete the method `migrationBuilder.AlterColumn` in the migration record without deleting the migration file.
This is the initial record.

[image]

Then I add a entity and re-migrate. Delete `migrationBuilder.AlterColumn` in the `Up` method.

[image]

The key in the database is changed.

[image]

Comment: Thanks... It worked for me... But is there a way that could do this automatically when adding new migrations? I mean is it right to change migration file manually? Because there isn't just one entity that use composite keys, there are almost 10 entities and doing this job each time we have a new migration is a little time-consuming task and... !

Comment: I read the official documents and similar problems, and there is really no such solution. Because the migration file is automatically generated by Entity Framework, manual change is correct.